# Computer repeatedly turns on and off

Tags: 16.04, server, shutdown

I finished installing Ubuntu Server on a computer, then shut it down.  About an hour later I go back and press the power button.  When I do the power light and the power and processor fans come on, but only for a second then everything goes of, then it tries again over and over.  What happened and how can I fix it?

Comment: It sounds like a hardware problem, maybe the power supply. Did you change the hardware configuration after you installed the server?

Comment: I took out the ram and it powered on fine.  So, I put the ram back in and on the third try it worked and it continues to work.  I don't know much about the hardware side of things, so I don't know if that makes sense or what that means for the ram.

Comment: The RAM probably wasn't seated correctly, and it was shorting out the power supply. They have to click into the locks to be in right. How many sticks of RAM? How many RAM slots? Are you sure that you installed the RAM to take advantage of memory interleaving?

Comment: Just one stick and four slots. And if I'm being honest, I don't know what memory interleaving is or how to install ram for it.

Comment: Simplified explanation: With matched pairs of memory sticks, most modern systems are using interleaving, which writes all the data to alternate memory sticks. First stick #1, then stick #2, then back to stick #1, etc. With just one stick, if you got 1-3 more sticks of exact similar sticks, and installed them into the correct slots, you'd have interleaving too. (with just 1, you'd normally install it into the lowest number slot, or bank A).

Comment: There's an update with a detail I forgot about.  When I took out the ram, I also disconnected the bluray drive and didn't plug it back in and now I've discovered when I reconnect it, the computer won't stay on.

Comment: Sounds like you found your real problem! A bad blu-ray drive!

Comment: Yeah, it's weird.  I had ubuntu desktop on it before and the drive worked fine.  I don't know what would have happened to it.

Comment: If you try connecting just the power lead to the blu-ray drive, see if the problem reoccurs again. If so, the blu-ray is shorting out the main power supply.

Comment: It still happens.  Last time after I unplugged the drive and reset the ram, it still took a couple tries for it to come on.  So is it the power supply that could be going bad?

Comment: Either one. Try the blu-ray in another computer.

Comment: I would, but I don't have another one.